# Can multiple BASH variable manipulations be used at once?

Tags: string, bash, variables, scripting

Is it possible to perform more than one bash variable manipulation in one shot?

For example:

```
# for this variable
foo="string_that_is_lower"

# can I do this in one shot?
$foo="${foo:0:4}"
echo "${foo^^}"
```

Is there a way to combine these? I realize this is a trivial problem because this works just fine, or one could simply use other built in tools like `echo ${foo:0:4} | tr [[:lower:]] [[:upper:]]`, but that is lame.

I've tried every logical combination I can think might work:

```
${${foo^^}:0:4}
${{foo^^}:0:4}
${foo^^,:0:4}
${foo^^;:0:4}
${foo^^ :0:4}
```

All produce syntax errors.

I find no instances of "(combine|multiple) bash variable manipulations" in the [Advanced Bash](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) [Scripting Manual](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html), or the manpage, or Google, or here, so maybe you just can't do it, but probably I'm just not searching for the right terms.

Comment: Answer - No.. *parameter expansion* acts on variables, not the text results of prior expansions. (but good question)

Comment: Maybe I should have googled "is it possible" before "how to do it". This makes sense though, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a very good question, but not something that *parameter expansion* allows. `man bash` provides that expansion operates on a **parameter name or symbol**, e.g.

> **Parameter Expansion**
>
> The `$' character introduces parameter expansion, command
>   substitution, or arithmetic expansion. The **parameter name or
>   symbol** to be expanded may be enclosed in braces, which are optional
>   but serve to  protect the variable to be expanded from characters
>   immediately following it which could be interpreted as partof the
>   name.

When you seek to chain expansions together, you are attempting to use the *text* that results from the first expansion as a *parameter name or symbol* (which it isn't), so the command fails with a syntax error.

Good question!

(**note:** to be complete -- there are some instances where you can embed a parameter expansion within another parameter expansion, but those are limited to where the outer expansion is looking for a single number as part of its expansion which can be provided by an included expansion such as the length of a string, e.g. `${#var}` in `v=foo; echo ${v:$((${#v}-1))}`)

Comment: I think having vaguely recalled seeing this kind of embeded parameter expansion before is probably the reason I assumed this was possible.

Very thorough explaination, thank you.